# Record a variation of a cell - excel

Tags: excel, function, random, charts, montecarlo

my problem is:

I have a matrix in excel then a function (repeated N times) that extract from this matrix a random number.
This happen everytime i hit F9 or everytime something change in the sheet.
After this i have another cell with a sum of all then numbers extracted. I would like to keep track of the change of this last cell in a linear chart to see how it goes on.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: search for macro (vba code) which will use `Calculate Event` of Worksheet to track cells changes. Macro Recorder doesn't support events therefore it's not a good starting point in your situation.

Comment: Why don't you store the values in an hidden sheet and then you generate the graph using it as source?

Comment: mucio i would love, how can i do it? (i mean the record the values in another sheet?

Comment: You can extract a random sample with either a worksheet formula, or a UDF, or a macro.  If you use a macro, the macro can store the sequential selections in a column, say column **Z**.  Then you can always compare the **SUM(Z1:Z99)** with **SUM(Z1:Z100)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: formulas

if you want to repeat T times, just instead of only 1 series of N number create a matrix of N by T. Then ad 1 last row (or column) under (or next to) the N functions for all T which contains the sum.

Now relate a chart to this last row (or column).

Solution 2: VBA

Create a piece of code that loops T times and copies the value of the cell with the sum into the next empty cell in a designate part of your excel workbook.

```
    Sub aaa
      dim i as Long
      dim T as Long

      T = 1000

      For i = 1 to T
        Range("rSum").Copy
        Cells(rows.count,1).offset(xlUp)).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

      Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is insuring that the values in A1, A2, A3, remain stable when A4 is added.

Comment: i already did all what u say. right now i have a cell with a sum =SUM(C30:C32;B30:B58;A30:A51) and i need to keep track of the change in this cell, if i do your way the number in each new cell under the first will grow....i only need to record the change!

Comment: Sorry I initially misread your question completely, I now corrected my answer(s)